# resize or scale png to specified size on splashscreen

Tags: java, resize, splash-screen

I would like to play a short animation of the png files on a splash screen

I am using the following file http://pastebin.com/HV0KqV4H

```
g.drawImage(img.get(frame),0,0,1280,720,0,0,640,360,null);
```

The original png are 640x360.

When I run the animation the png file are still in the same resolution. How can I rescale them to the resolution I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the answer. It turns out you cannot exceed the initial size of the png you call with command line.

So when you issue

```
java -splash:images/splash.png <Program>
```

the dimensions of the splash.png are final. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Probably you misplaced the right order of parameters or something like this.

Try using this one :

```
drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)
```

Comment: g.drawImage(img.get(frame),0,0,1280,800,null); I tried this .. still have the same stuff on screen :(